# I want to make gridview having functionality of column drag and drop

Tags: html, asp.net

I want to make Radgrid view having functionality of column drag and drop

Means column can be move 
ex. If we drag 1st column on 3rd column it will drop on 3rd position

in my case it is working but issue is only data is moving not header text.

I have used below code

```
<ClientSettings Selecting-AllowRowSelect="true" ReorderColumnsOnClient="true" ClientEvents-OnMasterTableViewCreating="SetGridHeight">
                                        <Selecting AllowRowSelect="True"></Selecting>
                                        <Scrolling AllowScroll="True" UseStaticHeaders="True"></Scrolling>
                                    </ClientSettings>
```

Comment: can anybody suggest me, what to do.

Comment: not familiar with asp.net but I don't believe that is valid HTML

Comment: then how can i reorder columns in radgrid

Comment: I reffered http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/columns-rows/columns/column-row-resize-reorder/defaultcs.aspx

Still it is not working.